# getDeclaredConstructors0(boolean)- line not available during tomcat startup in debug mode

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, dao, debug-mode

I have some trouble with my spring managed tomcat application.
There is a UserDao that is responsible for some User database operations.
If I start the tomcat I get this message:

```
Thread [pool-2-thread-1] (Class load: UserDao)  
Class<T>.getDeclaredConstructors0(boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Class<T>.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(boolean) line: not available    
    Class<T>.getDeclaredConstructors() line: not available  
    AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(Class<?>, String) line: 229 
    DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory).determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(Class, String) line: 962 
    DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory).createBeanInstance(String, RootBeanDefinition, Object[]) line: 935   
    DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory).doCreateBean(String, RootBeanDefinition, Object[]) line: 485 
    DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory).createBean(String, RootBeanDefinition, Object[]) line: 456   
    AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject() line: 294 
    DefaultListableBeanFactory(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry).getSingleton(String, ObjectFactory) line: 225  
    DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractBeanFactory).doGetBean(String, Class<T>, Object[], boolean) line: 291    
    DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractBeanFactory).getBean(String) line: 193   
    DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons() line: 605 
    XmlWebApplicationContext(AbstractApplicationContext).finishBeanFactoryInitialization(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory) line: 925 
    XmlWebApplicationContext(AbstractApplicationContext).refresh() line: 472    
    ContextLoaderListener(ContextLoader).configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ConfigurableWebApplicationContext, ServletContext) line: 383  
    ContextLoaderListener(ContextLoader).initWebApplicationContext(ServletContext) line: 283    
    ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent) line: 111 
    StandardContext.listenerStart() line: 4779  
    StandardContext.startInternal() line: 5273  
    StandardContext(LifecycleBase).start() line: 150    
    ContainerBase$StartChild.call() line: 1568  
    ContainerBase$StartChild.call() line: 1558  
    FutureTask$Sync.innerRun() line: not available  
    FutureTask<V>.run() line: not available 
    ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Runnable) line: not available 
    ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: not available 
    Thread.run() line: not available
```

Nevertheless every part of my webapplication works without problems.

That is the UserDao bean decleration in my spring-context:

```
<bean id="userDao" class="de.bc.qz.dao.UserDao" autowire="byName">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="LAU">
            <value>
                select u.* from quiz.user u where name like ?
        </value>
        </property>
        <property name="LUC">
            <value>
                select u.pc, u.gc, u.sc, u.bc from quiz.user u where name = ?
        </value>
        </property>
        <property name="LUID">
            <value>
                SELECT u.id
                FROM quiz.user u
                WHERE u.name = ?;
        </value>
        </property>
        <property name="LBQC">
            <value>
                SELECT u.name, u.cq
                FROM quiz.user u
                WHERE u.cq != 0 ORDER BY u.cq DESC LIMIT 0, 100;
        </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

and that my UserDao class:

```
@Service
public class UserDao extends AbstractSpring {

    private String mLAU;
    private String mLUID;
    private String mLBQC;
    private String mLUC;

    public void setLUC(String pLUC) {
        mLUC = pLUC;
    }

    public void setLAU(String pLAU) {
        mLAU = pLAU;
    }

    public void setLUID(String pLUID) {
        mLUID = pLUID;
    }

    public void setLBQC(String pLBQC) {
        mLBQC = pLBQC;
    }

    @Autowired
    public UserDao(DataSource dataSource) {
        setDataSource(dataSource);
    }

    @Autowired
    private UserMapper mUserMapper;

    public List<User> findAllUser(String pName) {
        return createJdbcTemplate().query(mLAU,
                new Object[] { "%" + pName + "%" }, mUserMapper);
    }

}
```

from the information given in the message I would say there are problems with constructors. But why? And more important where?

Comment: What is the type of that exception?

Comment: ok it is no exception... and it is only displayed if I start the tomcat in debug mode.

Comment: Then it just looks like some verbose (but not important) Tomcat warning or debug status message. I wouldn't worry too much about it, except for academic curiosity. Maybe Spring's class scanner is looking for a default constructor on @Service annotated classes or something (not a cause for concern). It does not seem to indicate a problem with your code. What version of Tomcat are you using, what version of the JRE are you using, and what version of the JDK did you compile with?

Comment: It is strange to see "line not available". In most of the cases, if the source files are not compiled with debug information you would see something like this in the stack trace - at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source). This happens mostly if JRE is used instead of JDK. Is that the case?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've experienced this error before you probably have a break point set somewhere on that class

In eclipse goto:

1. Window -> Show View -> Other
2. In the search box filter type: "Breakpoints"
3. In this break points view look for your UserDao class and uncheck
   all breakpoints inside it.

   This will make those msgs during startup go away

Comment: Realy good Airduster! You was right. It was a breakpoint in the line of the class definition.