# Repository class require bean entityManagerFactory could not be found

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, spring-boot, jpa

I am making a angular + spring application in and was trying to deploy it in same server. when i created back-end separately it worked fine all the process was working. but when i copied my angular project in spring project and configured in pom.xml and updated my maven and tried running the project it started giving me below error

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
=========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.8.RELEASE)

2019-09-24 16:13:29.074  INFO 3136 --- [           main] 
com.accounts.rtgsneft.Application        : Starting Application on HO-W- 
Ankushpc with PID 3136 (D:\Rocky\workspaces\acounts-projects\rtgs-neft- 
v1.0\target\classes started by Rocky in D:\Rocky\workspaces\acounts- 
projects\rtgs-neft-v1.0)
2019-09-24 16:13:29.076  INFO 3136 --- [           main] 
com.accounts.rtgsneft.Application        : No active profile set, falling 
back to default profiles: default
2019-09-24 16:13:29.530  INFO 3136 --- [           main] 
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data 
repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-09-24 16:13:29.584  INFO 3136 --- [           main] . 
s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository 
scanning in 48ms. Found 4 repository interfaces.
2019-09-24 16:13:29.910  INFO 3136 --- [           main] 
trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 
'org.springframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3c9c44bd] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-09-24 16:13:30.143  INFO 3136 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8086 (http)
2019-09-24 16:13:30.160  INFO 3136 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-09-24 16:13:30.160  INFO 3136 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.24]
2019-09-24 16:13:30.264  INFO 3136 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-09-24 16:13:30.264  INFO 3136 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1158 ms
2019-09-24 16:13:30.399  WARN 3136 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'beneficiaryController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'beneficiaryService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'beneficiaryMasterServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'beneficiaryRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'beneficiaryMasterRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3ac04654' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3ac04654': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
2019-09-24 16:13:30.402  INFO 3136 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-09-24 16:13:30.416  INFO 3136 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run 
your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-09-24 16:13:30.465 ERROR 3136 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

 ***************************
 APPLICATION FAILED TO START
 ***************************

Description:

Field beneficiaryRepo in 
com.accounts.rtgsneft.service.BeneficiaryMasterServiceImpl required a bean 
named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

i have tried all the solution on stack but none of them worked.

this are the solutions i have tried:

- [Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41738621/error-starting-applicationcontext-to-display-the-auto-configuration-report-re-r)
- [Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49004385/cannot-resolve-reference-to-bean-entitymanagerfactory-while-setting-constructo)
- [bean named 'entityManagerFactory' could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53923909/bean-named-entitymanagerfactory-could-not-be-found)
- [Spring Boot - repository field required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182426/spring-boot-repository-field-required-a-bean-named-entitymanagerfactory-that)
- [Field repository required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52402299/field-repository-required-a-bean-named-entitymanagerfactory-that-could-not-be)
- [Spring data jpa- No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined; Injection of autowired dependencies failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520602/spring-data-jpa-no-bean-named-entitymanagerfactory-is-defined-injection-of-a)

this is the solution i tried while debugging.

- [getDeclaredConstructors0(boolean)- line not available during tomcat startup in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27114001/getdeclaredconstructors0boolean-line-not-available-during-tomcat-startup-in-d)

my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.accounts.rtgsneft</groupId>
<artifactId>rtgsneft</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>rtgsneft</name>
<description>Gold's Gym Account department rtgs neft software</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/static/</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/rtgs-neft/dist/rtgs-neft</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

my BeneficiaryController .java

```
package com.accounts.rtgsneft.controller;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.accounts.rtgsneft.model.BeneficiaryMaster;
import com.accounts.rtgsneft.service.BeneficiaryMasterService;

/**
* @author Rocky
*
*/
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("beneficiary")
public class BeneficiaryController {

@Autowired
BeneficiaryMasterService beneficiaryService;

@GetMapping("all-beneficiary")
public ResponseEntity<?> getBeneficiaries() {
    List<BeneficiaryMaster> beneficiaries = beneficiaryService.gettingBeneficiaries();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(beneficiaries, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@PostMapping("new-beneficiary")
public ResponseEntity<?> postBeneficiary(@RequestBody BeneficiaryMaster beneficiary) {
    boolean beneficiaryRegistered = beneficiaryService.registerBeneficiary(beneficiary);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(beneficiaryRegistered, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@PostMapping("single-beneficiary")
public ResponseEntity<?> selectedBeneficiary(@RequestBody BeneficiaryMaster beneficiaryOBJ) {
    BeneficiaryMaster beneficiary = beneficiaryService.getBeneficiary(beneficiaryOBJ.getAccountNumber());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(beneficiary, HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

my BeneficiaryMasterService.java

```
package com.accounts.rtgsneft.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.accounts.rtgsneft.model.BeneficiaryMaster;
public interface BeneficiaryMasterService {
List<BeneficiaryMaster> gettingBeneficiaries();
boolean registerBeneficiary(BeneficiaryMaster beneficiary);
BeneficiaryMaster getBeneficiary(Long accountNumber);
}
```

my BeneficiaryMasterServiceImpl.java

```
package com.accounts.rtgsneft.service;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.accounts.rtgsneft.model.BeneficiaryMaster;
import com.accounts.rtgsneft.repos.BeneficiaryMasterRepository;
@Service
public class BeneficiaryMasterServiceImpl implements BeneficiaryMasterService {

@Autowired
BeneficiaryMasterRepository beneficiaryRepo;

@Override
public List<BeneficiaryMaster> gettingBeneficiaries() {     
    return beneficiaryRepo.findAll();
}

@Override
public boolean registerBeneficiary(BeneficiaryMaster beneficiary) {

    boolean benficiaryStatusFlag = false;
    BeneficiaryMaster benficiaryStatus= beneficiaryRepo.save(beneficiary);
    if(benficiaryStatus != null ) {
        benficiaryStatusFlag = true;
    }
    return benficiaryStatusFlag;
}

@Override
public BeneficiaryMaster getBeneficiary(Long accountNumber) {
    return beneficiaryRepo.getOne(accountNumber);
}
}
```

my BeneficiaryMasterRepository.java

```
package com.accounts.rtgsneft.repos;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.accounts.rtgsneft.model.BeneficiaryMaster;
@Repository
public interface BeneficiaryMasterRepository extends 
JpaRepository<BeneficiaryMaster, Long> {}
```

I hope this much data is enough to find out the issue.

If there is any other solution please recommend it to me.
I'm using spring 2.17
I want to deploy the application war file in tomcat and before doing that i have to test it for checking whether it's still working or not.

Comment: Your `pom.xml` doesn't match the logging output. The `pom.xml` has Spring Boot 2.1.7 and the output 2.1.8.

Answer (score -1):

Spring Data JPA by default looks for an EntityManagerFactory named entityManagerFactory. Check out this part of the Javadoc of EnableJpaRepositories or Table 2.1 of the Spring Data JPA documentation.

That means that you either have to rename your emf bean to entityManagerFactory or change your Spring configuration to:

(if you are using XML)

or

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="your.package", entityManagerFactoryRef="emf")

(if you are using Java Config)

Comment: Spring Boot automatically configures the `EntityManagerFactory` with the correct name.